# Only one defined value returned by d3.csv

Tags: csv, d3.js

When reading in a csv file in d3.js, only the first column reads in correctly. How do I get the other columns to return defined values?

I have tried converting the variables; e.g:

```
d.value=+d.value;
```

I have also searched and tried to match my lines of code to previous examples. The only difference I found is that other code examples had functions that accessed some of the variables more than once (i.e. there was a previous reference of the data in the code).

```
var data = d3.select(this).data()[0];

var htmlData = [
    data.id, 
    data.pd
];

div.html(htmlData.join("<br>"))
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 94) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 32) + 'px');        
}
```

My code, forked from [mbostock's](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/) block [Radial Cluster Dendrogram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339607):
https://blockbuilder.org/MyAkosombo/666f1d3791b90a5111d57cfa3b93c10b

Expectations:
I expect a tooltip that has the id and value shown when you hover over the name of the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` property is inside the property named `data`. This is the default outcome of the tree generator.

Therefore, it should be:

```
var htmlData = [
    data.id, 
    data.data.value
];
```

Here is your updated blockbuilder: https://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/0ba57a020d16b5b582605e9779697417